# Webview with multiple buttons to multiple URLs - Null pointer exception

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to use a fragment to make some buttons that when clicked will open in a Webview with different URLs. Eg. when i click the first button i go to "https://google.com/", second button to "https://fb.com" and so on.

I have made methods like so for each redirect (as I was using intents to redirect to a web browser in previous version):

```
private void goToGoogle(View view) {
    this.view = view;
    goToUrl("https://google.com");
}
```

The goToURL(String URL) method is simply an intent to open the browser with the URL as parameter.

Now, I have been asked to implement an in-app webview. I have the following code:

```
public void openWebView (String url){
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewActivity());

}
```

which I call with `openWebView(String.valueOf(R.string.googleURL));`.

My onCreateView method is declared as follows (example for 1 button, there are 16 on the real thing):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_imp_links, container, false);
    LinearLayout activityLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

    Button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.goToGoogle);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToGoogle(v);
        }
    });
```

I have also got this class in my app to handle the WebView:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Any help you can provide is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Definition of mWebView: `private WebView mWebView = new WebView(getContext());`

Comment: mWebView  is null here..post this class's complete code where you defined mWebView

Comment: `private WebView mWebView = new WebView(getContext());` this is my definition of mWebView @AshwiniViolet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a string from the resources, do not use `String.valueOf(R.string.googleURL)`.

Instead use [`Context#getString(R.string.googleURL)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getString(int)).